# What account to use for SharePoint 2010 Timer Job

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, administration, account, timer-jobs

what account do you run the SharePoint 2010 Timer Job service under?

Do you use the farm account or a separate one or just local service?

Currently I use the farm account but the health analyzer says, it's not a good idea to use an account that has local administration permissions.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old post but I felt it necessary to add a comment here: the farm account does NOT require local administration permissions (aside from during UPS provisioning) - that is the issue that the health analyser is flagging.

Answer (score 4):

[Technet - Account permissions and security settings (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx)

See **Farm service account**

> The server farm account is also
>   referred to as the database access
>   account and is used as the application
>   pool identity for Central
>   Administration, and as the process
>   account for the Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation 2010 Timer service. The
>   server farm account requires the
>   following permissions:

Answer (score 2):

The timer service needs access to the databases. That's the main thing. There's a separate service (SPAdminV4) which is used for local-admin operations. This approach keeps the vast majority of the code away from admin privileges. So yes, you really do want to use a different account for security reasons.